# I can't change the label value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a script in which the user would change some values of my game (player name, requirement to win), but he does not obey any of the conditions, much less change the value, simply give me an error that regardless of entered is displayed. as I am a beginner myself DOM and javascirpt I may have missed something already checked all possible errors I could make, but I did not find a solution

I left only the most essential parts of my code

```js
document.querySelector('#btn-apply').addEventListener('click', function() { // Apply the settings
    
    namePlayer0 = document.querySelector('#player-name-0').textContent // Current name of player 1
    namePlayer1 = document.querySelector('#player-name-1').textContent 
    inputNamePlayer0 = document.querySelector('#ipt-player-0').textContent // Name to be changed
    inputNamePlayer1 = document.querySelector('#ipt-player-1').textContent 
    winnerPoints = document.querySelector('.winner-condiction').textContent 
    iptScore = document.getElementById('ipt-score').textContent // Condition for the winner

    if(inputNamePlayer0 === '' || inputNamePlayer1 === '') { // Check if the inputs are empty
        document.querySelector('.msg').classList.add('warning')
        document.getElementById('warning-msg').textContent = 'Name fields are empty'
    } else { 
        document.querySelector('.msg').classList.add('sucess')
        document.getElementById('warning-msg').textContent = 'Values have been successfully changed'
        namePlayer0 = inputNamePlayer0 // The player's name is changed by the input value
        namePlayer1 = inputNamePlayer1
    }

    if(iptScore < 10 || iptScore > 300) {// Checks whether the entered value meets the requirements
        document.querySelector('.msg').classList.add('warning')
        document.getElementById('warning-msg').textContent = 'Condition to win cannot be greater than 300 and less than 10'
    } else {
        winnerPoints = iptScore // Input value entered is stored the condition
    }
})
```

```css
#config {
  font-family: 'Poetsen One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#646464;
}

#config input {
  border: 2px solid #646464;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  font-family: 'Poetsen One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #919191;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
  text-indent: 40px;
}

#config input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 10px rgba(57, 182, 78, 0.5),
              0px 0px 15px rgba(57, 182, 78, 0.5);
}

#config label {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#lbl-player-0 span::before,
#lbl-player-1 span::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900; content: "\f4ff";
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#lbl-score span::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900; content: "\f091";
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#config label span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  text-indent: 25px;
}

.sucess {
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #0c794f;
  position: relative;
}

.sucess::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900; content: "\f058";
  color: #0c794f;
}

.warning {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
.warning::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900; content: "\f071";
  color: red;
}

.action-btn {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
              0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
              0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
              0 8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

#btn-apply {
  font-family: 'Poetsen One', sans-serif;
  margin: 30px 0px ;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  
}
#btn-apply > i{
  font-size: 17px;
}


.winner-condiction {
  font-family: 'Poetsen One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #919191;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
#player-name-0, #player-name-1, .action-btn, #dice-title  {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Junar', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='CSS/teste.css' >
        <link rel="icon" href="CSS/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='CSS/fontawesome-free-5.11.2-web/css/all.css'>
        <title>Dice - The Game</title>
    </head>
        <section id='board'>          
            <!-- PLAYER 1 -->
             <div class='player-0 active' id="player-0">
                <span id='player-name-0'> Player 1</span>  
            </div>

            <!-- PLAYER 2 -->
            <div class='player-1' id="player-1">
                <span id='player-name-1'> Player 2 </span>
                <div class='winner-condiction'>Winner Condition: <span class='score' id='score-player-1'>5</span></div>
            </div>   
           
        </section>

        <!-- SETINGS-->
        <section id='config'>
            <!-- Configs -->
            <h1 id='text'><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>Change or modify the name of the players<span id='warn'> (8 Characters)<span></h1>
            <!-- Name Player 1 -->
            <label id='lbl-player-0'> 
                <input id='ipt-player-0' type="text" maxlength="8" minlength="4" placeholder='Name Player 1' class="ipt-name-change"></input>
                <span></span>
            </label>
            <!-- Name Player 2 -->
            <label id='lbl-player-1'>
                <input id='ipt-player-1'type="text" maxlength="8" minlength="4" placeholder='Name Player 2'class="ipt-name-change"></input>
                <span></span>
            </label>

            <h1 id='text'><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Reset the Winner conditions</h1>
                <!-- Condiões para o vencedor  -->
            <label id="lbl-score">
                <input id='ipt-score' type='number' placeholder='Score to Win' class="ipt-name-change"></input>
                <span></span>
            </label>
                <!-- Error Mensages  -->
            <div class='msg'>
                <span id='warning-msg'></span>
            </div>
            <button class='action-btn' id='btn-apply'><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Aplicar</button>
           </section>
    <body>
```

Comment: iptScore = document.getElementById('ipt-score').textContent is a string not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.value`, not `.textContent`.

**Explanation:** The `textContent` property is used to get contents of paragraphs, headings, etc., but not for getting a text input's value. For text inputs, `textContent` returns an empty string!

Instead, you should use `value`, as shown in the snippet below:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#whatever");
input.onchange = function() {
    console.log(input.textContent);
    console.log(input.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="whatever"/>
```

Comment: I understand, I really hadn't seen it, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

Get the inputs' `value` not `textContent`.

```js
document.querySelector('#btn-apply').addEventListener('click', function() { // Apply the settings

  namePlayer0 = document.querySelector('#player-name-0').textContent; // Current name of player 1
  namePlayer1 = document.querySelector('#player-name-1').textContent;
  inputNamePlayer0 = document.querySelector('#ipt-player-0').value; // Name to be changed
  inputNamePlayer1 = document.querySelector('#ipt-player-1').value;
  winnerPoints = document.querySelector('.winner-condiction').textContent;
  iptScore = document.getElementById('ipt-score').value; // Condition for the winner

  if (inputNamePlayer0 === '' || inputNamePlayer1 === '') { // Check if the inputs are empty
    document.querySelector('.msg').classList.add('warning');
    document.getElementById('warning-msg').textContent = 'Name fields are empty'
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.msg').classList.add('sucess')
    document.getElementById('warning-msg').textContent = 'Values have been successfully changed'
    namePlayer0 = inputNamePlayer0 // The player's name is changed by the input value
    namePlayer1 = inputNamePlayer1
  }

  if (iptScore < 10 || iptScore > 300) { // Checks whether the entered value meets the requirements
    document.querySelector('.msg').classList.add('warning')
    document.getElementById('warning-msg').textContent = 'Condition to win cannot be greater than 300 and less than 10'
  } else {
    winnerPoints = iptScore // Input value entered is stored the condition
  }
  
  document.querySelector('#player-name-0').innerHTML = namePlayer0;
  document.querySelector('#player-name-1').innerHTML = namePlayer1;
  document.querySelector('.winner-condiction').innerHTML = winnerPoints;
})
```

```css
#config {
  font-family: 'Poetsen One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #646464;
}

#config input {
  border: 2px solid #646464;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  font-family: 'Poetsen One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #919191;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
  text-indent: 40px;
}

#config input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 10px rgba(57, 182, 78, 0.5), 0px 0px 15px rgba(57, 182, 78, 0.5);
}

#config label {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#lbl-player-0 span::before,
#lbl-player-1 span::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f4ff";
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#lbl-score span::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f091";
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#config label span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  text-indent: 25px;
}

.sucess {
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #0c794f;
  position: relative;
}

.sucess::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f058";
  color: #0c794f;
}

.warning {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

.warning::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f071";
  color: red;
}

.action-btn {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

#btn-apply {
  font-family: 'Poetsen One', sans-serif;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

#btn-apply>i {
  font-size: 17px;
}

.winner-condiction {
  font-family: 'Poetsen One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #919191;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#player-name-0,
#player-name-1,
.action-btn,
#dice-title {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Junar', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='CSS/teste.css'>
  <link rel="icon" href="CSS/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='CSS/fontawesome-free-5.11.2-web/css/all.css'>
  <title>Dice - The Game</title>
</head>
<section id='board'>
  <!-- PLAYER 1 -->
  <div class='player-0 active' id="player-0">
    <span id='player-name-0'> Player 1</span>
  </div>

  <!-- PLAYER 2 -->
  <div class='player-1' id="player-1">
    <span id='player-name-1'> Player 2 </span>
    <div class='winner-condiction'>Winner Condition: <span class='score' id='score-player-1'>5</span></div>
  </div>

</section>

<!-- SETINGS-->
<section id='config'>
  <!-- Configs -->
  <h1 id='text'><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>Change or modify the name of the players<span id='warn'> (8 Characters)<span></h1>
            <!-- Name Player 1 -->
            <label id='lbl-player-0'> 
                <input id='ipt-player-0' type="text" maxlength="8" minlength="4" placeholder='Name Player 1' class="ipt-name-change"></input>
                <span></span>
    </label>
    <!-- Name Player 2 -->
    <label id='lbl-player-1'>
                <input id='ipt-player-1'type="text" maxlength="8" minlength="4" placeholder='Name Player 2'class="ipt-name-change"></input>
                <span></span>
            </label>

    <h1 id='text'><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Reset the Winner conditions</h1>
    <!-- Condiões para o vencedor  -->
    <label id="lbl-score">
                <input id='ipt-score' type='number' placeholder='Score to Win' class="ipt-name-change"></input>
                <span></span>
            </label>
    <!-- Error Mensages  -->
    <div class='msg'>
      <span id='warning-msg'></span>
    </div>
    <button class='action-btn' id='btn-apply'><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Aplicar</button>
</section>

<body>
```

Comment: I put the answer below for the explanation of the reason, but thank you very much for commenting on my error